# Flutter - Setting wrap content to Vertical scroll List view

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

- I have a page with SingleChildScrollview as parent and have multiple horizontal scrollview and on bottom I have a vertical scroll Gridview(Disable the the scroll of Gridview).
  The problem is I want to wrap the height of the Gridview with the height of the child items, without giving specific height to the Gridview

[image]

Comment: I need more info, but make sure you are using Expanded() to wrap your widgets. Sometimes this works. I can't see your code to be sure though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to wrap the `Gridview` with a `Flexible` widget, Make sure you are not using any of the `Expanded` widget and `Spacer` widget in `Gridview` children.